# I want to add an interactive calendar on my website

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, xhtml

The first problem is, what language can I write this in?
I have access to PHP, MySQL, ASP, ASP.NET, Javascript, Java, etc. (I wanted to avoid Java so I wouldn't have to make the user install the JRE).

What I want is this:

1. You go to my website, you click the calendar button (on the nav bar) and it will open up almost like in the same way Facebook has it's pictures open up (with a popup, faded background) minus the click out to exit (I want to have an X on the top of it for that purpose).
2. The calendar would then have areas highlighted different colors depending on the event (because I want the user to see events listed in each day).
3. Also, I wanted to admin to be able to add events to the calendar via an application interface (hopefully!) and for the events to be stored somewhere.

This sounds like an application on a website, which I have no knowledge of where to start and I feel like it would take more than XHTML and CSS.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Grab some water to put out the flames.

Comment: jQuery UI Datepicker:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I would recommend "jQuery datepicker". Google it. It doesn't come with an admin panel or such, but it may be useful to you so you could modify it. I'm pretty sure there are also better opensource (free) calendars around. I'd go for PHP, but that's because I feel better when using PHP.

Good luck!

Comment: What about PHP makes you feel better (not too experienced with it so I would genuinely like to know).

Comment: This seems perfect, thank you! But how could I get an admin, who is logged in, to be able to add to the calendar?

Comment: It's just how I personally feel about it. I had C# / ASP.net at school too and I did not like it one bit. In my opinion PHP is easier to lean and understand (even though many programming sometimes look quite alike) and I think there's better documentation. However I must say that I'm a webdeveloper so PHP would be quite the right language for me to pick.

Comment: First off you would need a database (mysql). Create a table for the events and such. You could use HTML to create a login form (so also have an user table in the database) and if the filled in form info matches the one in the database, create a PHP session and with that session you could access specific pages you need to develop where you can add/edit events and such.

Comment: From the sound of it, it's really beneficial to learn PHP. That will be my next step. I appreciate all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

OFC this is one way to do it, not the only way.

For the look it will be XHTML and CSS.
For popping up the calender in a FB-Image style you can use AJAX/JQuery.
For managing events, PHP can do it.